# List of all static-ralated tags and elements, and how to get all static from a beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, static

I working on a beautifulsoup finding of all elements that are related to static.

What is the list of all static-related tags and elements?

Is there any other way apart from finding by multiple `BeautifulSoup.findAll()` with different arguments?

my current best version looks like

```
stitic_ = souped.findAll('link', rel='stylesheet') + \
          souped.findAll('img') + \
          souped.findAll('script') + \
          souped.findAll('video')
```

if it's only correct, maybe there are some elements I passed through.

Comment: I think `findAll` is a Beautifulsoup3 method, still compatible with 4th version. Its new name is `find_all`

Comment: `find_all(['img', 'script', 'Video'])` will match these tags at once

Comment: And that would get all the static? So nothing is missing, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()`- For more take a minute to [check BeautifulSoup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

So based on your question you could chain your tags:

```
soup.select('img, script, video, link[rel="stylesheet"]')
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, cannot give u a vote thoough (not enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

`find_all` accepts a function as parameter that can be used to filters the tags, see [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

```
def filter_static(tag):
    if tag.name in {'img', 'script', 'video'}:
        return True
    elif tag.name == 'link':
        for attr in tag.attrs.get('rel', {}):
            if attr == 'stylesheet':
                return True
    return False

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for i, match in enumerate(soup.find_all(filter_static)):
    print(f"[{i}] {match}")
```